# Change global proxy on windows and calling that program using cmd (CLI)

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, proxy

I have the following idea:

An application which is going to change the **global proxy** settings from my machine (just Windows 7/8 for now). I would like to be able to call that script / program in CMD like this:

`program.exe -start //the program is initialized and ready to be used`

`program.exe -nextip //the program will replace the actual ip with the ones that I have into a .txt file.`

`program.exe -close //this will close the application and the IP will be the old one`

Now, my question is: what is the best approach to do this ? ( what programming language). Would preffer something like: C / C++ / C# or Bash. I don't need a GUI for it.

More, could you please help me to understand the steps that I have to go through in order to accomplish this ? How should I parse the arguments in order to have them recognized in CMD for example.

I will update this thread with the solution as there could be somebody else who needs it. Thanks !

Comment: You should be able to do this with a script.  You should definitely not try to do this in C or C++.

Comment: So, a script. I should write it in bash ? Is this possible ? I will be able to change the GLOBAL proxy using just a bash script ?

Comment: Check this question: http://superuser.com/questions/29701/global-proxy-settings-for-windows

Comment: It doesn't help me too much. Any other hints ?